# Why locks made on objects, instead of code in java

Tags: java, multithreading

We have the below syntax in Java.

```
public synchronized void count() {
    count--;
}
```

This can be modified like the below.

```
public void count() {
    synchronized(this) {
        count--;
    }
}
```

My Question is , Why can't we write the code like the below in Java?

```
public void count() {
    synchronized {
        count --;  
    }
}
```

In fact, I want to understand the difference b/w `synchronized(this)` and `synchronized(other)`

Comment: You'll have to ask James Gosling et al

Comment: It is not just a matter of opinion.  There are clear technical reasons why locking on objects is better than locking "on code".  (Locking "on code" is more or less the same as what a `static synchronized` method does ...)  The thing that is debatable is that >>all<< objects can function as locks in Java ... but that's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: In your case you should use an AtomicInteger.

Comment: Objects hold state, not code, so there would be no way to lock i.e. change the state of code.

Comment: What you could do is make `synchronized {` a short hand for `synchronized (this) {` however I would say that synchronizing on an object which is visible to the caller breaks encapsulation so it perhaps for the best they didn't do this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write code like below code you mentioned.

Synchronized block is always used to lock an **object** for any shared resource.
Scope of synchronized block is smaller than the method. That is the difference between synchronized block and method.

```
class Table{  

 void printTable(int n){  
   synchronized(this){//synchronized block  
     for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){  
      System.out.println(n*i);  
      try{  
       Thread.sleep(400);  
      }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
     }  
   }  
 }//end of the method  
}
```

Above is an example of synchronized block where it blocks other threads from synchronizing on the same object.

Comment: You said "Synchronized block is always used to lock an object for any shared resource." why?

Comment: You say that the synchronized block in your example "blocks the current `Table` object."  Well, that's true if "blocks" means "blocks other threads from _synchronizing on_ the same object," but a lot of newbies will read that and think that "blocks" means "blocks other threads from _accessing_ the same object," which is not true at all.  It's a very common newbie mistake to think that if one thread synchronizes on some object while writing it, then it's safe for other threads to access it without synchronization.